# Rails: How to access current controller in an Observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, observer-pattern

I need to access the current controller or flash a notice from an observer method.

```
class SomeObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :some_model
    cattr_accessor :current_controller

    def after_create(record)
        ...
        current_controller.flash[:notice] = "Some message!"
    end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter do
        SomeObserver.current_controller = self
    end
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated, accessing the controller from an observer somewhat violates the MVC principle. Also the given answers fit your specific use case.

**But** if you need a more general solution you might try to adapt the way Rails **Sweepers** are working.

Sweepers are ordinary observers, but they provide access to the controller, *if* the observer is called from a controller action.

This is achieved by using the sweeper as both observer and controller **filter** simultaneously, which is easily possible because observers are singletons (i.e. they include the **[Singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html)** module)

In a nutshell, you have to do this:

1. Create your observer as usual.
2. Add the singleton instance as `around_filter` to your controller:

   ```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     around_filter MyObserver.instance #, only: [...]
   end
   ```
3. Add the methods for the filter to your observer:

   ```
   attr_accessor :controller

   def before(controller)
     self.controller = controller
     true #Don't forget this!
   end

   def after(controller)
     self.controller = nil
   end
   ```

Now you can access the controller from the observer callbacks. However `controller` is `nil` if the observer was triggered outside a controller action.

Comment: This is a very clever approach and is exactly the approach used in the Audited gem to retrieve the current_user (via the controller) in order to create an audit trail on modified objects.  https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn´t work under Rails 4.2 anymore.

I´ve had to extend your approach. 

Details can be found  here https://gist.github.com/raebo/62e68427ed27f21bafda

Answer (score 2):

Accessing Controller from Observer violates MVC pattern. The way to do it without violating MVC is to assign `flash[:notice]` from controller after calling `SomeModel.create()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why in the observer? You should put the flash assignment in your controller, the reason being that the flash is a view level concern.

**Alternatively**

Make a helper method in your application_helper file that checks flash and diplays.

```
def show_flash
[:notice, :error, :warning].collect do |key|
  content_tag(:div, flash[key], :id => key, :class => "flash flash_#{key}") unless   flash[key].blank?
end.join
end
```

Then in your layout just add

```
<% show_flash %>
```

For notice, warning, and error types of messages, this checks to see if any of them are set, if so it prints them out, if not then nothing is printed.

and now you can just use

```
flash[:notice] = "Some message!"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My app logic requires these computations to be made in an observer. I observe various models and callbacks are not suitable for this purpose. I know its not MVC way of doing things and may be I have to move it in background task/process and make some notification mechanism to notify the front end, but I'm looking for fast solution to this problem.

Comment: well is the alternative way not helpful ? you can flash[:notice] from anywhere..!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection in Rails between observers and controllers and I fear you won't get your goal with a standard way. However I suggest to use threads to get this goal.

Comment: Why did you provided the same link to this discussion?